# PHP: uploaded images are not found in folder

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to upload multiple image in folder and also save in database. Problem is that, my images are not moving in folder. i don't know why? but same code is running on localhost. I paste my code please help me:

```js
var abc = 0;      // Declaring and defining global increment variable.
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 //  To add new input file field dynamically, on click of "Add More Files" button below function will be executed.
 $('#add_more').click(function() {
  $(this).before($("<div/>", {
   id: 'filediv',
  }).fadeIn('slow').append($("<input/>", {
   name: 'file[]',
   type: 'file',
   id: 'file'
  }), $("<br/><br/>")));
 });
 // Following function will executes on change event of file input to select different file.
 $('body').on('change', '#file', function() {
  
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
   
   abc += 1; // Incrementing global variable by 1.
   var z = abc - 1;
   var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
   $(this).before("<div id='abcd" + abc + "' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src=''/></div>");
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
   reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
   $(this).hide();
   $("#abcd" + abc).append($("<img/>", {
    
    id: 'img',
    src: 'x.png',
    alt: 'delete'
   }).click(function() {
    
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
   }));
  }
 });
 // To Preview Image
 function imageIsLoaded(e) {
  
  $('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
 };
 $('#upload').click(function(e) {
  
  var name = $(":file").val();
  if (!name) {
   
   alert("First Image Must Be Selected");
   e.preventDefault();
  }
 });
});
```

```css
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans";
form{
 background-color:#fff
}
#maindiv{
 width:960px;
 margin:10px auto;
 padding:10px;
 font-family:'Droid Sans',sans-serif
}
#formdiv{
 width:500px;
 float:left;
 text-align:center
}
form{
 padding:40px 20px;
 box-shadow:0 0 10px;
 border-radius:2px
}
h2{
 margin-left:30px
}
.upload{
 background-color:red;
 border:1px solid red;
 color:#fff;
 border-radius:5px;
 padding:10px;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0 green;
 box-shadow:2px 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.75)
}
.upload:hover{
 cursor:pointer;
 background:#c20b0b;
 border:1px solid #c20b0b;
 box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.75)
}
#file{
 color:green;
 padding:5px;
 border:1px dashed #123456;
 background-color:#f9ffe5
}
#upload{
 margin-left:45px
}
#noerror{
 color:green;
 text-align:left
}
#error{
 color:red;
 text-align:left
}
#img{
 width:17px;
 border:none;
 height:17px;
 margin-left:-20px;
 margin-bottom:91px
}
.abcd{
 text-align:center
}
.abcd img{
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 padding:5px;
 border:1px solid #e8debd
}
b{
 color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="image.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="image_style.css">
<div id="filediv"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/></div>
<input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add More Files"/>
<button id="save" name="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm upload" id="upload">SAVE</button>
```

```
   if(isset($_POST['save'])){   

    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++){

        $image = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]; 
        $target_path = "http://rental.thedigitalmarketingonline.com/uploads/vehicle_snap/".$image;  
        if(($_FILES['file']['size'][$i] < 100000)){

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)){

                echo '<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }else{    

                echo '<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        }else{    

            echo '<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: check image folder permission on server ?

Comment: can you try giving real path instead of URL here "http://rental.thedigitalmarketingonline.com/uploads/vehicle_snap/"

Comment: i also gave real path like: $target_path = "../../../../uploads/vehicle_snap/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first as @Gautam said, use form tag to be able to submit data,

second `$target_path` should be a real path such as `"uploads/vehicle_snap/"` as satya said

third this is not a good security practice, there is no filters to filter if this is an image or not so an attacker may upload php files and compromise your server/website

try filtering uploads by checking if the extension of the files is an image extension, you can do this by doing this:

```
$allowed_ext = ["png","jpg","jpeg","etc.."];
if(in_array(end(explode('.',$file['name'])),$allowed_ext)){
    //uploading code goes inside here
}
```

Comment: i used form tag in my coding. i cut this code from between that's why form tag are missing and i also gave real path like: $target_path = "../../../../uploads/vehicle_snap/"  but its not working.

Comment: try to `cd` into the vehicle_snap folder and execute `pwd` in there for a more accurate path

Answer (score 0):

I guess your data is not getting posted as you have not used form tags.
try using this and check if it works

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div id="filediv"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/></div>
<input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add More Files"/>
<button id="save" name="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm upload" id="upload">SAVE</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i use form tag.